# MySql query is executing for every record in table

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so i have a query:

```
    UPDATE  example_table
    SET     some_column = :some_data,
            else_column = :else_data;
            asd_column = :asd_data,
            xyz_column = :xyz_data,
            abc_column = :abc_column,
            qwe_column = :qwe_column,
            fgh_column = :fgh_column,
            tyu_column = :tyu_column,
            bnm_column = :bnm_column
    WHERE   id = :user LIMIT 1

$p->bindParam(':user', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$p->bindParam(':some_column', $this->some_column, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$p->bindParam(':else_column ', $this->else_column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$p->bindParam(':asd_column ', $this->asd_column, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$p->bindParam(':xyz_column', $this->xyz_column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$p->bindParam(':abc_column', $this->abc_column, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$p->bindParam(':qwe_column', $this->qwe_column, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$p->bindParam(':fgh_column', $this->fgh_column, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$p->bindParam(':tyu_column', $this->tyu_column, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$p->bindParam(':bnm_column', $this->bnm_column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The problem is that this query is updating every record in `example_table`
and of course i checked that it is getting executed only once 
as so as `$this->id` is valid and it's getting parsed to the query 
couse it's the only condition.

I have no idea what's causing this problem, any suggestions, maybe someone had similar issue.

Comment: I did run this query with and without `LIMIT 1` and it make's no difference

Comment: @b.desai why? The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: do all records have an ID or are some values null? do all records have the same :user? is there a PHP loop surrounding this update statement causing it to be run for each user or something?

Comment: there is no loop in my code, and `:user` is a unique id of a user

Comment: there are nulls in table but i dont update these columns, `:user` of course cann't be null

Comment: So logically the where clause and limit don't appear to be making it to the database  what's the php logic look like for the build of the SQL string that is being executed?

Comment: so the named bind paramater is :some_column but the query shows it as :some_data, :else_date etc... that looks off to me.

Comment: `... else_column = :else_data;` :: You dont want a semicolon here...

Comment: If you don't want gremlins, you always use surrogate primary key (or, `auto_increment` if you will). This query is going to update every record if, and ONLY IF, every record has the same value for the `id` column. There's no need to run the query to assert that. What's happening is: you either have all `id`'s the same or you're inside some sort of a loop repeating this process. What it is - that's up to you to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that because you have semicolon in middle of your statement (near to `else_column = :else_data;`)

```
UPDATE  example_table
SET     some_column = :some_data,
        else_column = :else_data;
        asd_column = :asd_data,
        xyz_column = :xyz_data,
        abc_column = :abc_column,
        qwe_column = :qwe_column,
        fgh_column = :fgh_column,
        tyu_column = :tyu_column,
        bnm_column = :bnm_column
WHERE   id = :user LIMIT 1
```

will be executed as

```
UPDATE  example_table
SET     some_column = :some_data,
        else_column = :else_data;
```

while it should be like this

```
UPDATE  example_table
SET     some_column = :some_data,
        else_column = :else_data,
        asd_column = :asd_data,
        xyz_column = :xyz_data,
        abc_column = :abc_column,
        qwe_column = :qwe_column,
        fgh_column = :fgh_column,
        tyu_column = :tyu_column,
        bnm_column = :bnm_column
WHERE   id = :user
```

Comment: That's the right answer :) btw. i also found it few moments ago, and i felt so dumb ;d cheers :)

Comment: it happen always  :)

Comment: @esquarial : you would have *found* it an hour ago if you had read the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the spurious `;` by a `,` ::

(note: the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT 1` on an update statement are either mysql extensions, or errors. In either case, the order of the affected row(s) is not guaranteed)

---

```
UPDATE  example_table
SET     some_column = :some_data,
        else_column = :else_data, -- << HERE!
        asd_column = :asd_data,
        xyz_column = :xyz_data,
        abc_column = :abc_column,
        qwe_column = :qwe_column,
        fgh_column = :fgh_column,
        tyu_column = :tyu_column,
        bnm_column = :bnm_column
WHERE   id = :user LIMIT 1
      ;
```